# Install .EXE without displaying windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, batch-file, automated-install, command-line-interface

I want to install an .exe file without displaying windows, by supplying value to parameters ? How can i do from Commands or script not in UI ?

Comment: Without knowing what program you're trying to install the best possible answer we can give you is: *Cabbage*.

Answer (score 2):

The program you are trying to install requires silent command line parameters. There is no one size fits all to this.

Comment: I got there is no fixed size, but in automation in large sector it should be